# Set top and left attribute in rich:modalPanel via js

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I use `rich:modalPanel` of RichFaces and I'm trying to set the `top` and `left` attributes (which defines where the window appears on the screen) via JavaScript. I'm trying to get the offset of another element and make the window appear in the same offset. Didn't succeed so far.

What I did:

```
<rich:modalPanel top="document.getElementById('some_element').offset().top()"
left="document.getElementById('some_element').offset().left()">
```

But it's not working! The window appears always on the top-left corner.
*Note*: when I alert the result from `document.getElementById('some_element').offset().left()` or `document.getElementById('some_element').offset().top()` it's giving me the right position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@top and @left need a String value, if you put JavaScript there it's going to be treated as a String.

The `show` method from the panel's JS API takes two arguments - event and options, so you can do this:

```
#{rich:component('panelId')}.show(null, {
    top: document.getElementById('some_element').offset().top(),
    left: document.getElementById('some_element').offset().left()
 });
```